# Why is my Python program running faster on the CPU than on the GPU with CUDA?

Tags: python, numba

So I was following [this](https://weeraman.com/put-that-gpu-to-good-use-with-python-e5a437168c01) tutorial, basically running this code in Python (3.7.4) on Windows 10:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def pow(a, b):
    return a ** b

def main():
    vec_size = 100000000

    a = b = np.array(np.random.sample(vec_size), dtype=np.float32)
    c = np.zeros(vec_size, dtype=np.float32)

    start = timer()
    c = pow(a, b)
    duration = timer() - start

    print(duration)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**The problem: Different results than in the tutorial (which uses a 1050Ti)**

When target is set to 'cuda', which means it's running on my GTX 970 (driver 441.41), the program takes ~0.6 seconds to run.
But when set to 'parallel', which is multiple cores on the CPU (i5 4690k), it only needs ~0.1 seconds.
Even setting it to 'cpu', so it uses only 1 cpu core, it runs faster than the GPU, at ~0.4 seconds.

So have I maybe configured my GPU incorrectly somehow? As far as I can tell, the whole installation of the CUDA toolkit has not gone wrong.

Also, when I run the thing, in Windows Task Manager I see a slight rise of the graph for a short amount of time ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjEs5.png)), so it does appear to use the GPU, but maybe not as ideally as it could.

I don't really know what I can do here - google didn't lead me to a solution unfortunately. Any suggestions on what is going on here? Can I test this in another way? In case I cannot solve this: Are there any good alternatives to CUDA?

Comment: The example is probably too simple to benefit from GPU acceleration, code does not always run faster in the GPU.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro nailed it, GPUs are not a silver bullet.

Comment: @konfeu have you found if it was the matter of example or something different? In case if it is the problem with example, maybe you have some better example to share to see that cuda configuration of working as expected?

Comment: @koralgooll Unfortunately I didn't find out what caused the issue. I did some other things since then, so I never got back to it.